# Правильная конструкция выборки laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, выборка

Есть таблица `booking` в ней есть две колонки `user_id` и `status` мне нужно сделать выборку по конкретному пользователю с учетом нужного статуса, попытки мои построить правильно запрос не обвенчались успехом вот небольшие наработки:

```
$Booking->checking = Booking::where('user_id', 6)->get();
```

Этот запрос выводит данные корректно, а вот продолжение:

```
$Booking->checking_status = $Booking->checking->where('status', 'sale')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'approved')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'complaint')->get();
```

На выходе нужно получить пользователя №6 у которого есть статусы `approved`, `sale`, `complaint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Booking::where('user_id', 6)->whereIn('status', ['sale', 'approved', 'complaint'])->get();
```